# Magento Site Design

Tags: discussion, design

My name is Joshua and I'm a product designer at Stack Overflow. First off, congratulations on your community moving out of beta!

#### Graduation and Your Site Design

Graduation comes with a few perks. One of those perks is community-specific design, reflecting your unique theme, topic, and culture. Many elements will be altered to help make your site unique, while retaining common elements with Stack Exchange communities. These common elements help show you are part of the Stack Exchange network.

---

#### Design Concept

Most Stack Exchange communities are formed around a topic. Magento Stack Exchange is unique in that it has formed around a product, which already has an established branding. Given that many users who might use and frequent this website will probably already have some familiarity with Magento, the product; we wanted to create a theme which acknowledged Magento's branding, but was still distinct from the product.

**Building Blocks**

[image]

Magento's brand approach, in our estimation, is to utilize colors and shapes to reinforce how the product gives users a foundation upon which to build on. Combining these primary shapes with a warm orange-red palette and a clean, no-nonsense look, we feel we've a look which gives a nod to Magento, but is still distinctly yours.

---

#### Color Scheme

The color scheme builds on Magento's use of orange, black, and white; adding in a few additional colors to help create enough variance.

[image]

---

#### Logo

This was a tough one. As we cannot use Magento's logo for copyright reasons. Yet we didn't want to strike out in a completely different direction. In the end we created logo which captures the essence of Magento's logo, but is still unique to the community. The style of the logo is minimal, clean, and utilizes simple shapes.

[image: Magento Logo Lineup]

We matched the sharp, angular glyph with a friendly, humanist typeface. We think this juxtaposition of these two elements work nicely together.

[image: Single Color, Full Version]

---

#### Swag

[image: Branded Site Materials]

---

#### Overall Site Design

To view the site designs at full-scale, click on the images.

[image: Homepage]

[image: Questions Page]

---

We believe this design captures the unique theme and topic of your community. We would love to hear your feedback. If there are no major design changes, we hope to launch the site design soon!

Thank you for for making this such a great community!

Comment: I personally love it and you really took the look of the Magento brand to heart here. I was hoping that you would follow this design direction [from my post about it nearly 3 years ago](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/a/83/336) and you've really done it. I think it looks splendid. Reinventing the Magento logo is a bit of a bold step; but I do like the use of the hexagon throughout the design. +100 from me.

Comment: Me people will be in touch with your people, I've stressed the importance of collaboration on our side of the house. Thanks for the work so far.

Comment: Joshua, I wanted to thank you and your team for all the great work put into this design.  It's clear that you invested a significant amount of effort in understanding both the Magento Brand and the spirit of the Magento SE community that has grown in this venue! Can't wait to see the final design and order some swag!

Comment: This is awesome. We are finally getting out of anonymity. I love the hexagonal vote buttons and badges.  On a side note... Is it just me, or the logo looks like [magneto's helmet](http://media-dominaria.cursecdn.com/attachments/109/398/635120394045310961.png)? Not that I'm complaining or something.

Comment: Looks totally cool! But yeah, the helmet can't be unseen :)

Comment: Fantastic. Absolutely nailed the design - and as above, the hexagon upvotes are an excellent touch.

Comment: Awesome, that design is in full respect of Magento and adds the uniqueness we needed, can't wait to see it live!

Comment: @Marius Sigh. [Unfortunately once it's seen, it cannot be unseen.](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B6DK0U4CMAA1EJ0.jpg)

Comment: @philwinkle Thanks for linking to this post. Before I started design explorations, I searched the Magento Meta community for posts tagged with [tag:design], but I couldn't find any. It's nice to know that we were of the same mind without even knowing it. :)

Comment: @Bryan'BJ'Hoffpauir Thank you. Pitching a site design is an exciting moment in a community's life. And we love being a part of that. I should note that the swag mockup are just some quick ideas and we'll be soliciting ideas for swag ideas as well.

Comment: @benmarks Any feedback you might have, I'd appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: as @Marius pointed out, it just totally looks like Magneto's helmet, and will account for all the times people type Magneto instead of Magento :p

Comment: Awesome, where do we buy the shirts? We can also print them for Meet Magento attendees :).

Comment: @GuidoJansen Must resist the urge to spend all my $$$ and #BuyAllTheMagentoThings !

Comment: @SanderMangel It's all good, my friend.  Joshua was able to pull that feat off all ninja-style and with "effortless effort" because the #RealMagento SE Community is SO meta....in fact we're meta^meta (M2, get it?)  I'm blowing minds & dropping Mics? I've been spending some quality time with philwinkleshair lately and I think it's rubbing off on me! For the record, minds would have been blown nuclear-style if SE supported <sup>tags</sup> tags in the comments, just saying.

Comment: Should totally have a `Flush Cache` button to make post edits visible :P #JustMagentoThings

Comment: @Bryan'BJ'Hoffpauir it's morning, barely had a cup of coffee and I start reading your comment. By the end I lost it :D

Comment: I want to order thirts and mugs with is awesome magento helmet!

Comment: Love the design, looks great (especially the up/downvote buttons). And yes, I cannot unsee the helmet ever again ;)

Comment: stunning..nice work @Hynes . when we get free t-shirts :)

Comment: Ok, so you're all going to hate me for saying this now, but I'm going to officially blame @kalenjordan who "induced this clearly psychotic vision" by basically just talking on the phone like he always does - the new logo isn't JUST kind of like Magneto - it's Magneto somehow mixed with old school Cobra Commander from GIJOE http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBMQD.jpg *MIC DROPPED 4 REALZ* enjoy y'alls weekend NOW

Comment: For the official SE record, Kalen is going to be inducing psychosis no matter what any of us do, and I still think the work that @Hynes and the SE team did for our community is #AWESOMESAUCE - so thanks!

Comment: Looks awesome  with new design with specialty with updated badges icon...:-)

Comment: awesome design, hope to see it in action soon

Comment: I like 3rd Color Scheme. Does not like helmet Pattern.@Hynes, As per as,my thought, we should try other pattern

Comment: I like this logo! Great design, clean, and I'm personally a fan of the helmet allusion.

Comment: I love the design, Good Job, the logo is like a helmet, cool!

Comment: get the orange color for the design, or something cool man!

Comment: Very nice design and also attractive .

Comment: So...when are we getting the new design with the awesome h̶e̶l̶m̶e̶t̶ logo?