# Magento — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

> **This has been shipped today!** Enjoy your swag, everyone :)
>
> If you still don't have yours and think you should have it by now, please send me an e-mail so I can look into it *instead of leaving a comment here*. :)

---

**We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!**

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

Comment: Wooohoo! This is awesome!

Comment: happy to see  my  name on list waiting .... :)

Comment: Oh wow this is so cool!

Comment: Oh how about top 100? coming from the guy at 92 ;) very cool though either way.

Comment: this is so cool!

Comment: wait is over got  my mail within one hour great speed..

Comment: Awesome !!! That will motivate users

Comment: This is the another motivation tool for me. Thank you.

Comment: This is totally awesome,,happy to see my name....:-)

Comment: This is super cool and motivating. :)

Comment: Awesome ..!  Thank you very much

Comment: Wow!! Thanks :)

Comment: ahhhh i am on 127

Comment: So now the real question - how do we actually verify that you are indeed an employee of SE and not just someone constructing a socially engineered form to collect our addresses?

Comment: Aside from me having a diamond next to my name here, @KristofatFooman, you can also find me in [the team page](http://stackoverflow.com/company/team) ;)

Comment: Really nice! I guess they won't be sent (and have arrived) before Meet Magento NL :( @SanderMangel

Comment: Oh no, definitely not, @7ochem :\

Comment: 77th only :-/ Too bad i missed it by 5 places. Any chance the number can be extended ? I like the idea :)

Comment: Thank you, that's very cool!

Comment: That really awsome & cool. I have thought that i will add this t-shirt at my professional Profile..That must add  some value at my profile  :)

Comment: Why doesn't this post have 72 upvotes yet?

Comment: My name is Ben, that's mentioned twice on the first page alone (Ben Lessani and Ben Marks) so I should get 2 tshirts right?

Comment: @JNat,where the form? am waiting for this?

Comment: @JNat, That's fantastic, but i haven't get any token on my email or where we fill up form?

Comment: I sent out an e-mail about an hour after this post was made. If you can't find the e-mail, look in your spam folders. If it's not there, let me know and I'll send it your way again.

Comment: Yep, check your spam. Found it there as well ;)

Comment: @Ben-Space48. you get to personally deliver the t-shirts to Ben Lessani and Ben Marks

Comment: Hard luck. M on #84.!! wish that was for the users on the third page too.! But am glad to see myself there.! good initiative :)

Comment: Ben Marks is never in one country for more than 35 seconds so tracking him down might be difficult, I'll just keep his T shirt for safe keeping.

Comment: @JNat did not get any confirmation email from you?

Comment: Just confirmed, and I sent it to you, @QaisarSatti. Did you check your spam folder?

Comment: @JNat i am talking about after submitting the form.

Comment: You mean you filled the form and were expecting to receive a confirmation e-mail from me, @QaisarSatti? In that case, it's normal that you didn't receive one, 'cause I don't confirm every entry as it goes in ;)

Comment: @JNat i just want to know is other stackexchange community users also get shirts ?

Comment: Communities get swag as their designs are rolled out, @BabyinMagento

Comment: The form doesn't allow Chinese address  :( Please help !

Comment: Won't using a romanized version of the address get to you anyway, @Fra?

Comment: @JNat thank you ... I'll get it deliver in Italy ... I want to be sure it wont get 'lost in translations'  ;)

Comment: Did anyone get t-shirt ? :-)

Comment: It hasn't been shipped yet, @KeyurShah. And it might still take a while, as I mentioned in the e-mail.

Comment: Thanks for confimation @JNat Do you have any idea when it will be shipped ?

Comment: As I mentioned in the e-mail, @KeyurShah, 6-8 weeks.

Comment: While we've been waiting for our MagentoSE shirts to arrive (and had another MageStackDay last Friday/Saturday), some of us decided to wear a fake MagentoSE Shirt @JNat :D Thought this would be fun for you to find out about. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all

Comment: Ahhh lol - I was wondering why some people "received" swag a head of schedule!

Comment: My shirt arrived today here in AT. Thanks! :)

Comment: My shirt and stickers arrived weeeeeeeeeeeeee thank you!!!! :) (In Canada)

Comment: Hi @JNat, we did not get any t-shirt  at india.Do you have shipped the t-shirt at india

Comment: We shipped to all the users who filled the form just a week ago, @AmitBera. Please allow for a bit more time for stuff to get to you. If you don't get anything by the end of the month, then please shoot me an e-mail so I can look into it.

Comment: @JNat thanks  4 ur quick reply

Comment: @JNat Thank you I got the t-shirt in India..:)

Comment: @JNat i did not receive any t-shirt in pakistan

Comment: Please shoot me an e-mail, @QaisarSatti, and I'll have a look :)

Comment: Hi, is this "promotion" still active? Would like to have such a shirt too ;)

Comment: Hey @sv3n: this was a one-off thing, as a celebration of the site design launch. We do offer swag to users when they reach 100k reputation points, though :)

Comment: Okay ... just give me another week :P

Comment: OMG! I actually missed my email even though I was among the top 72. I know this is 1+ years old, But still if possible I'd love to have this T-shirt

Comment: @JNat, as you told, you will offer the t-shirt for 100k reputation users, Right now i am having near to 3k. 97k more only to get 100k. Can you please offer me as advance?

Answer (score 7):

happy to see finally they read my comment

[Magento Site Design](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/817/magento-site-design)

[image]

Great Response

**Your response has been recorded. You can expect your swag to arrive in the next 6 to 8 weeks! Or you can at least hope so... I hope so...**